# Gradle ignores priority in testng

Tags: java, gradle, automated-tests, testng

Can someone explain how does gradle works with **priority** parameter in @Test annotation in testng?
For example I have the next code:

```
public class TestGradle {
    @Test (priority = 2)
    public void testA() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Test A");
    }
    @Test (priority = 1)
    public void testB() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Test B");
    }
    @Test (priority = 3)
    public void testC() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Test C");
    }
}
```

So if I will run it via `gradle test --tests TestGradle` I will get the next output:

```
Test A 
Test B
Test C
```

but I thought, that it should be like this:

```
Test B
Test A
Test C
```

Comment: which version of TestNG you are using?

Comment: testng:7.0.0-beta3

Comment: I have the same issue in TestNG: 7.3.0, Gradle: 6.7.1  Is anybody figured this out?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a bug in TestNG. I created an [issue](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/2170).
It is fixed with 7.5 and later versions.

---

You can create a workaround to solve this problem.
With an `IMethodInterceptor` you can change the execution order of your methods.

```
public class ExecutionOrderInterceptor implements IMethodInterceptor {
    @Override
    public List<IMethodInstance> intercept(List<IMethodInstance> methods, ITestContext context) {
        Comparator<IMethodInstance> comparator = new Comparator<IMethodInstance>() {
            private int getPriority(IMethodInstance mi) {
                int result = 0;
                Method method = mi.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();
                Test a1 = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
                if (a1 != null) {
                    result = a1.priority();
                }
                return result;
            }

            public int compare(IMethodInstance m1, IMethodInstance m2) {
                return getPriority(m1) - getPriority(m2);
            }
        };

        IMethodInstance[] array = methods.toArray(new IMethodInstance[methods.size()]);
        Arrays.sort(array, comparator);
        return Arrays.asList(array);
    }
}
```

To use this interceptor you need to add an annotation to your test classes:

```
@Listeners({ TestReportListener.class })
public class MyTestClass {
...
```

You can also create an abstract class which your test classes extend:

```
@Listeners({ TestReportListener.class })
public abstract class BaseTest {
  //Add here common code
}
```

And use it in your test class:

```
public class MyTestClass extends BaseTest {
...
```

**Note:** You can use such an interceptor also to implement a custom execution order.